# MultiSelectSegmentedControl load item issue when UIView is right to left

Tags: swift

when i write code

```
UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

[MultiSelectSegmentedControl](https://github.com/yonat/MultiSelectSegmentedControl) behave weird

[image]

In English with this code it works fine

```
UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MultiSelectSegmentedControl` uses `UIStackView` internally, so its left-right layout changes according to `semanticContentAttribute`. I fixed the problem in version 2.3.5, but note that now the order of segments will be from right to left.